# Override the meaning of the font-size keywords in modern non-IE-quirksmode browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-size, quirks-mode

I'm rewriting a web app that allowed users to submit snippets of html via a WYSIWYG editor. The web app was designed from the ground up to be IE-only and quirksmode-only. As a result the html submitted by users was designed with this in mind.

One data item, for example, includes the following html:

```
<span style="font-size:small">Element name here</span>
```

Which incorrectly renders as `font-size:medium` in quirksmode (the way the user designed it), but renders properly as `font-size:small` in all other browsers including IE in standards mode.

I'm forcing IE into standards mode but I still want the app to look the same to existing users, so I'm looking for a way to override the font-size keywords in modern browsers to mean what they do in quirksmode. In other words I want the modern browsers to incorrectly render the text as `font-size:medium`. I'll contain all current user-submitted html in containers with class "old-user-content" or something similar.

For now I'm willing to resort to severe hackery to get this done. Any advice?

Comment: You only want to override this font size setting within `.old-user-content`, right?

Comment: Preferably yes, but I don't use the keywords anywhere else so won't make much difference if overridden globally for now. Theres a lot of scope for refactoring down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to do this:

```
@media { 
       .old-user-content { font-size: medium } 
       }
```